# Hostage movie where a rich daughter is kidnapped for money

Tags: identify-this-movie

In the begining there is a guy that wants to find a good job and when he goes home, his mother is very sick and when he goes to buy the medicine, it's very expensive and he has no money. Then he works out how to get the money: he and his 2 friends (I think a woman and a man, one I think takes drugs) kidnap the daughter of a rich family and they take her hostage in the vacation house this rich family uses in the summer.

After 3 quarters of this film, you understand that this daughter's family have a servant that is the dad of the guy that kidnapped their daughter and blackmails them for money. He has a Zippo to light cigarettes and when she is kidnapped, she listens to the Zippo and in the end of the film, almost understands that he was her kidnapper - but the whole thing went successfully and if I'm not wrong, he kills all his friends.

Summary: Son of a poor family that has a sick mother and his father works for this rich family kidnaps their daughter to blackmail them for money and it's a success. I think it's from about 5 years ago or so.

Comment: can you please summarise the whole thing and make it the title of the question so as if someone is also clueless tomorrow with this movie type he/she can identify this easily. you will get +1 from me.

Comment: zippo = lighter, I guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [The Entitled](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1650535/combined) from 2011 with Kevin Zegers, Tatiana Maslany and Ray Liotta, but they don't only kidnap a rich daughter, they kidnap *three* kids from rich families, 2 sons and a daughter.

> Paul Dynan's life is turned upside down when he decides to kidnap three young socialites and hold them ransom to save his family. Things spiral out of control when his psychotic partners get trigger happy and his victims come with their own surprises. When blood is shed and his perfect plan goes horribly wrong, Dynan must fight to stay one step ahead of his own twisted game.

Paul's mom is sick and his dad turns out to be the butler of one of the families. Him and his 2 partners (a boy and a girl) keep the rich kids in a house belonging to the father of one of them. After his partners are eliminated in the end, Paul gets away with it. Here's the trailer:

Answer (score 1):

May it be "[The Last House on the Left](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0844708)"?

Storyline:

> While being transported by two detectives in a car, the dangerous
>   criminal Krug is rescued by his brother Francis and his girlfriend
>   Sadie, and they brutally kill the detectives. Meanwhile Emma, her
>   husband Dr. John and their seventeen year-old daughter Mari
>   Collingwood head on vacation to their house nearby the lake. Mari
>   borrows the family car to meet her friend Paige that is working in a
>   store in the town. They befriend the teenager Justin in the store and
>   he offers some marijuana to the pothead Paige in the motel where he is
>   lodged. While they are smoking grass in Justin's room, Krug, who is
>   Justin's father, Francis and Sadie arrive and abducts the girls. Krug
>   drives Mari's car and she provokes a crash on a tree. Krug stabs Paige
>   and rapes Mari; however Mari manages to escape, swimming in the lake,
>   but Krug shoots her in the back. They walk through the isolated road
>   in the woods and they reach Collingwood's house telling that they have
>   just had a car accident.